# Limit of a sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Calculate the limit of the following sequences:

1-  $U_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{\sqrt{k}}{n\sqrt{n}}$

2-  $U_{n}=\sqrt[n]{(1+(\frac{1}{n})^{2})(1+(\frac{2}{n})^{2})...(1+(\frac{n}{n})^{2})}$

**My Attempt**

1-  $U_{n+1}-U_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\sqrt{k}}{n\sqrt{n}}-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{\sqrt{k}}{n\sqrt{n}}=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{\sqrt{k}}{n\sqrt{n}}+\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n\sqrt{n}}-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{\sqrt{k}}{n\sqrt{n}}=\frac{1}{n}>0$

So this first sequence is increasing but for it's limit I don't know if it's going to tend to infinity or to a finite number. Thank you for any help before hand.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** These seem to be exercises related to Riemann Sums. For example,

$1.$
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\sqrt{k/n}\frac1n
$$
is a Riemann Sum for
$$
\int_0^1\sqrt{x}\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
$2.$
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\log\left(1+\frac {k^2}{n^2}\right)\frac1n
$$
is a Riemann Sum for
$$
\int_0^1\log(1+x^2)\,\mathrm{d}x
$$

Comment: @Module: And as far as the second exercise is concerned, take the logarithm first, and it will become a Riemann sum as well.

Comment: @robjohn Thanks! So for the first one I found that limit is that the limit is $2/3$. Correct?

Comment: @Module: that looks correct.

Comment: @robjohn Concerning the second one, do I take the logarithm of the sequence and then when I find the limit I use the exponential?

Comment: @Module: the logarithm is uniformly continuous on compact subsets of $(0,\infty)$ and the exponential is uniformly continuous on compact subsets of $(-\infty,\infty)$. That means they commute with the limits in this question. (Yes)